# mysql workbench doen't show complete menu when right clicked on tablename

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to mysql workbench and found that the menu that appears when a table name is right clicked, is not visible in my version.Is there any method to get that without having to uninstall and install it again?

I have added the snip with the current right click menu i get now.

[image: snip]

Comment: What version do you have? And which os?

Comment: WB version 5.7.22 on ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: 5.7.22 is MySQL Server version, what is the Workbench version?

Comment: Workbench version 6.3